# GROK Pattern for Thread Name (LogStash 8.2.0)

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am new to LogStash. So I am learning GROK patterns and how to extract data from log lines. So I am using Logback to print log lines. The layout in the logback.xml is something like:

```
%date{dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZ} [%-5level] [%thread] %logger{40} - %msg%n%xThrowable
```

So it normally prints a log output in a file like:

```
07/06/2022 14:37:41.471 +0530 [WARN ] [main] com.cmt.trial.logging.LoggingTrial - Trying to log an warn
```

Now so far, I have got to:

```
%{DATE_EU:date} %{TIME:time} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:zone} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.*]
```

Which does pull out the date, time, time zone and the log level. But I am not able to think of a way to extract `[main]` which is the thread name. Any pointers on this would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use DATA instead of GREEDYDATA knowing that the thread name is inside brackets https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.8/libs/grok/src/main/resources/patterns/grok-patterns

Comment: @dcolazin Could you please make it the answer so that i can select it. Thanks. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `DATA` (regex `.*?`) instead of `GREEDYDATA` (regex `.*`) (code [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.8/libs/grok/src/main/resources/patterns/grok-patterns)), knowing that the thread name is inside brackets, so something like

```
%{DATE_EU:date} %{TIME:time} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:zone} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \] \[%{DATA:thread_name}\].*
```